# Axios return Cannot GET /[object%20Object] when calling axios.get()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I had an issue with the axios.get() when I tried to call my API from the frontend, it returned but when I test my backend with postman it is okay.

> Cannot GET http://localhost:3040/v2/user/[object%20Object]

Please check code below:

> backend api

```
router.get(
  '/:user_id',
  userAuthorization,
  async (req, res) => {
    const _id = req.params.user_id;
    try {
      const user = await getUserById({ _id });
      if (!user) {
        res.status(404).send('User not found!');
      }
      res.json(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server error!');
    }
  }
);
```

> frontend

```
    const user_id = useParams();
    useEffect(() => {
        loadLevels();
        adminGetUserById();
      }, []);
    
      const adminGetUserById = async () => {
        console.log('user id ---> ', user_id);
        await axios
          .get(`http://localhost:3040/v2/user/${user_id}`)
          .then((user) => {
            console.log('user res ---> ', user.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
          });
      };
```

and it return result below, the API request URL should be like this `http://localhost:3040/v2/user/62aec70881e46a4794b3a424`. I don't know why it returns `[object%20object]` in URL.

Please check the image error result below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrmqd.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka2gf.png

Comment: You must desegregate the useParams hook, cause right now you are using an object. It must be like: `const {userId} = useParams()`. Please replace `userId` in the snippet by your actual parameter name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the posted images I can see the log for `user_id` is in this format:

```
{ user_id: 'your id' }
```

This means `useParams();` is returning an object with the property `user_id` inside it.

So what you want is to extract that property.
To do that, as [@osmanys-fuentes-lombá](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15056711/osmanys-fuentes-lomb%C3%A1) mentioned you should do somehting like:

```
const { user_id } = useParams();
```

This should assign the value direct to the `user_id` and not create an object with `user_id` as a property.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer of @Renato, variable `user_id` is an object `{user_id: '62aec...'}`. When JavaScript constructs string `http://localhost:3040/v2/user/${user_id}`, it will internally call `object.toString()` which will result in `[object Object]`, thats why you will see

> Cannot GET http://localhost:3040/v2/user/[object%20Object]